# craete json configuration file to optimize parameters in RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, json, scikit-learn, grid-search

I define a dictionaire containing some paramters to optimize with RandomizedSearchCV as follow

```
import numpy as np

from time import time
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# get some data
digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target

# build a classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)

# specify parameters and distributions to sample from
param_dist = {"max_depth": [3, None],
              "max_features": sp_randint(1, 11),
              "min_samples_split": sp_randint(1, 11),
              "min_samples_leaf": sp_randint(1, 11),
              "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}

# run randomized search
n_iter_search = 20
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search)
```

Now I would like to put the same parameters in a json file...is it possible?

I created a json file as the one below

```
{
"max_depth": [3, null],
"max_features": ?,
"min_samples_split": ?,
"min_samples_leaf": ?,
"bootstrap": [true, false],
"criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]
}
```

but I don't know how pass the parameters wiht "**?**"

Comment: Do you want to store in json the params which are already searched in `RandomizedSearchCV`, after calling `fit()`? Because if they are not searched, means they are not sampled yet from the distribution, so there's no way to know which integer will be sampled from `sp_randint`.

Comment: nope....instead of defining the search space in the code I would like to define it in a json file that I will load into a dictionary and pass to the RandomizedSearchCV

Comment: max_depth will be serialized as `"max_depth": [3, null]`,

Comment: Thats why I'm asking. json will only serialize values not functions. You may need to define a different structure, something which will specify the params of `sp_randint` and then at the time of loading, convert that to appropriate function call.

Comment: I think you can use pickle here, if your only objective is to save them and load at later time.

Answer (score 0):

numpy arrays are not JSON serializable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33647962)